# Form "lags" after drawing bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I have a relatively simple windows application. It uses about 15 controls.

My constructor method looks like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Paint += this.Teken;
}
```

My Teken method (simplified) looks like this:

```
private void Teken(object o, PaintEventArgs pea)
{
    if (start)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Text == "Basic")
            Bitmaps.DrawBitmap1(pea.Graphics, bitmapsize, max);
    }
}
```

My DrawBitmap1 method sets every pixel a certain color and then draws a bitmap using the Graphics.DrawImage method.

After the bitmap is drawn, the controls become really laggy and it takes more than a second to select text in a textbox. The main form just gets really slow.

I can understand the bitmap to be drawn slowly but I can't understand this.

Is there a simple solution to my problem?

EDIT:

Here's the Drawbitmap1 code:

```
public static void DrawBitmap1(Graphics gr, int bitmapsize, int max)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(bitmapsize, bitmapsize);

        for (int x = 1; x < bitmapsize; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y < bitmapsize; y++)
            {
                int mandelnumber = CalculateMandel(x,y)

                if (Form1.mandelnumber == max) 
                    bitmap1.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
                else if (Form1.mandelnumber %2 == 0) 
                    bitmap1.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                else 
                    bitmap1.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
            }
        }
        gr.DrawImage(bitmap1, 50, 100);
    }
```

mandelnumber is a variable calculated in another part of the program.

EDIT2:

I've run a profiler and it seems that the method CalculateMandel() doesn't stop running after it's been through every pixel of the bitmap. How is this possible?

EDIT3:

Turns out the DrawBitmap1 function is called again when hovering over textboxes or buttons. How is this possible, I don't have any hover events, not even TextChanged events..

Comment: A suggestion (might not even be a good one) but have you checked the size of the bitmap? If it's big it will be slow(er).

Comment: The size of the bitmap is 450 x 450. But the problem is really the laggy controls after drawing the bitmap. Before I draw the bitmap, they aren't laggy at all.

Comment: Clearly there's something wrong with DrawBitmap1().  Nobody can guess at what it might be if you don't post its code.

Comment: I added DrawBitmap2() to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.Paint += this.Teken;
```

This is wrong, it will call your `Teken` routine every time your app needs repainting; when you open your window, when you resize your window, when you change focus, move another window, get a tooltip, change resolution or themes, practically all the time. In fact, about the only time `Teken` is not called is when `CalculateMandel` is finished and you need to show the results. You never call `Invalidate` so you are never alerted when you need to draw your results.

> ... `CalculateMandel()` doesn't stop running after it's been through every pixel of the bitmap. How is this possible?

Because you are specifically telling it to recalculate everything in your bitmap every time anything changes in your U.I.; over and over and over again. Unless only your bitmap changes, then you don't tell it to repaint. Completely backward. This will also lock up your U.I. as you are uselessly recalculating your bitmap even if it doesn't need redrawing.

> ... `DrawBitmap1` function is called again when hovering over textboxes or buttons. How is this possible, I don't have any hover events

But something else does; perhaps a tooltip. And you have told your app to call `CalculateMandel()` every time anything in your app U.I. (except your bitmap) changes.

The problem is you have two totally separate things going on; your app needs to repaint the U.I. when something changes, and you have a calculation (`CalculateMandel()`) that you want to update the U.I. when it's done. These are separate events and you must handle them separately.

First, get rid of `this.Paint += this.Teken;`; that's causing your problems and will not do what you want.

Second, create a `BackgroundWorker` that calls `CalculateMandel()` in its `DoWork` event and in your `ProgressChanged` event returns the completed bitmap then calls `yourWindowOrPanelOrWhatever.Invalidate()` to redraw the new data.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DrawBitmap1` method probably some level of conversion from whatever bitmap the source is, to whatever bitmap is supported by the drawing surface.  That could be different colour densities, different bit densities, etc (maybe scaling?).  That usually takes a bit of extra time.

I would suggest using a `PictureBox` control instead.

In addition, if you are going to need to re-draw the image you want to display, then I suggest only doing when the image changes, not when you draw/paint the screen--that will lead to reduced performance.  e.g.

```
pictureBox.Image = DrawBitmap1(gr, bitmapSize, max);
```

If you are going to change you image more than a couple of times a second, I recommend you do not use SetPixel because you will never get a performance acceptable to refresh the screen.

On problem with doing on the paint is that when a pain occurs and when the bitmap needs to change are not always the same time.  You could refresh the form when you need to change the bitmap, but you reduce performance on all other draws of the form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried using a picturebox, but it didn't help.

Comment: Really, you're using `SetPixel` for each pixel in the picture and just assigning a bitmap to the `PictureBox.Image` property wasn't *any* faster?  I find that hard to believe.

Comment: But the bitmap I have to draw differs everytime so I can't just use a bitmap. I have to calculate how every pixel of the bitmap looks. I still need to set every pixel seperately, even when using a PictureBox.

Comment: @BrunoCarvalhal ah, more essential information to providing a correct answer...  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it by eventually using a picturebox and stopped using the paint event at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ever time your form repaints you have a very expensive, O(n2) algorithm running, and it is not very well optimized at that.

It looks to me like you're doing a lot of redundant work that need only be performed once.  Your `DrawBitmap1` function generates one of three images (to a bitmap that you never even display, is that right?).

You could also rip the if statements out of the inner loop and just create three versions.  There is no need to check the same condition so many times as it is not changing between iterations.

You could create each image once and cache it.  If that image is needed again, just return it directly from the function.

On top of that, the `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()` functions in GDI+ are horrendously slow.  I mean, really, *really* slow.  Any real image processing in .NET is likely to be done in an unsafe context using a pointer directly to memory.  Call `Bitmap.LockBits`, which returns a `BitmapData` object, and use the `Scan0` proeprty to retrieve a pointer to the memory buffer.

Comment: No I do display the bitmap, I draw it to the window. Also, I need the if statements in the inner loop because I need to check them for every single pixel in the bitmap. Also, the image won't be needed again so caching is also not an option. About the SetPixel(), I understand that this would cause a slow creation of the bitmap. But when the bitmap is created and drawn to the window, the other controls shouldn't lag, right?

Comment: @BrunoCarvalhal: `bitmap1` goes out of scope when the function returns, so I don't see how you are using it.  You do not in fact need the if statements in the inner loop because they check a variable *which never changes*.  You could have three separate loops which do the same thing without all of the branching.  If the image won't be needed again then why are you performing this operation so many times?  It is called each time the window refreshes, which is why you are seeing "lag".

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. If you look at the edited question, you'll see the difference now. the variable mandelnumber is calculated again for each x,y coordinate in the bitmap.

Comment: @BrunoCarvalhal: Ah, ok then.  I think your major problem stems from a misunderstanding of the Paint event.  That event will be fired whenever a portion of the control needs to be repainted.  When exactly does this image actually need to be updated?  Is it only when some option changes?  Also, you're only ever using `mandelbitmap`, `bitmap1` goes out of scope when the function returns (and you do not call `Dispose()` on it either).

Comment: I'm sorry, DrawBitmap1() actually draws bitmap1 instead of mandelbitmap. I made this error while trying to simplify my code. Also, the image needs to be updated everytime a button_click event, a mouse_click event or a mouse_wheel event is triggered. But Teken() is now called everytime I hover over a textbox or a button. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: @BrunoCarvalhal: Ok, so don't use the Paint vent handler, it is the wrong event.  Handle the Click events for every control that you need to and, in each of them, call the same method to draw your image.

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed it by eventually using a picturebox and stopped using the paint event at all.